# I want to display one post per page through pagination. But pagination buttons not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display one post per page and that is working fine. But when pagination button is pressed nothing happens. I want upon clicking pagination button next post should be displayed.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custom Page 2*/?>
<html>
<body>
<div id="posts_">

<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<section class="post">
        <h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>
        <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
    </section>';
endwhile;
?>

</div>
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
      pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);
  } ?>
  <div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what your `pagination()` function is (and does it output any JS to override hrefs and other markup or bind events), but it seems your links have empty `href` attributes, so they do nothing.

Use `paginate_links()` function to output correct navigation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

See an "Example With a Custom Query". It might help:

```
<?php 

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages
) );

?>
```

This article can be usefull as well:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination